# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' FLUTTER

Tags: database, api, flutter, android-studio, mobile

I'm more new to Flutter. I want to fetch category and product information from the API. I don't have a problem with the category, but when fetching the products, I get the error
"Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap <String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable '".

I saw many examples of this error, but I could not relate it to myself.

(Product Api)

```
static Future<http.Response> getProductsByCategoryId(int categoryId){
    return http.get(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:3000", "products?categoryId=$categoryId"));
  }
```

(Product Class)

```
class Product {
  int id;
  int categoryId;
  String productName;
  String quantityPerUnit;
  double unitPrice;
  int unitsInStock;

  Product(this.id, this.categoryId, this.productName, this.quantityPerUnit,
      this.unitPrice, this.unitsInStock);

  Product.fromJson(Map json){
    id = json["id"];
    categoryId = json["categoryId"];
    productName = json["productName"];
    quantityPerUnit = json["quantityPerUnit"];
    unitPrice = double.tryParse(json["unitPrice"].toString()) ;
    unitsInStock = json["unitsInStock"];
  }
```

```
Widget buildProductList(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(itemCount: widget.products.length, itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return Text(widget.products[index].quantityPerUnit);
      }),
    );
```

```
void getProductsByCategoryId(Category category) {
   ProductApi.getProductsByCategoryId(category.id).then((response){
     setState(() {
       Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
       this.products = list.map((product) => Product.fromJson(product)).toList();
     });
   });
```

Comment: can you post the value returned by ProductApi.getProductsByCategoryId(category.id) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the following part

Before

```
return http.get(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:3000", "products?categoryId=$categoryId" ));
```

After

```
 return http.get(Uri.http("10.0.2.2:3000", "products", {"categoryId" : "$categoryId"}  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly cast the returned map from the json.decode
`Final list = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>(); this.products = list.map((product) => Product.fromJson(product)).toList();`

Maps are not iterable in dart: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/collection-in-dart-17493ac9e704